# Div table-cell vertical align not working

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to simply center text horizontally and vertically using DIV and display type as table-cell but it is not working in either IE8 or Firefox.

Below is the CSS that I am using and that is all that is in the html page.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html, body
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
div.Main
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
div.MainHeader
{
    color:#C00000;
    font-size:18pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    width:800px;
}
div.BlackBox
{
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#FFFF00;
    display:table-cell;
    float:left;
    font-size:18pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:191px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:630px;
}
div.BlackBoxPicture
{
    background-color:#000000;
    float:right;
    height:191px;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:170px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 47):

I think `table-cell` needs to have a parent `display:table` element.

Comment: And, possibly, a `display: table-row` element between them.

Comment: Wait.. you have them floated. Remove the float? Please post a jsfiddle. You may want to use `inline-block` instead. It helps seeing the visuals, though.

Comment: @mattgcon, `display: table-cell` works, and allows `vertical-align` to be used in both Chrome and Firefox without any issues (on Ubuntu 10.10): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8At93/). Using `float` on the `display: table-cell` elements does, however, break that ability it seems: [JS Fiddle demo with `float`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8At93/1/)

Comment: Same problem if you have it absolutely positioned.

Comment: Ahh, the things we do to avoid just using a table...

Answer (score 40):

This is how I do it:

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table
}
#content {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    Content goes here
</div>
```

See

[Example of vertical centering](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center-example)

and

[CSS: centering things](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html).

Comment: This works only if the element isn't floated. The asker's Blackbox element has float:left; which is where the problem comes from.

Comment: Easy to forget the `height: 100%` on `html`

Answer (score 11):

You *can* vertically align a floated element in a way which works on IE 6+. It doesn't need  full table markup either. This method isn't perfectly clean - includes wrappers and there are  a few things to be aware of e.g. if you have too much text outspilling the container - but it's pretty good.

---

**Short answer:** You just need to apply `display: table-cell` to an element *inside* the floated element (table cells don't float), and use a fallback with `position: absolute` and `top` for old IE.

---

**Long answer:** Here's a [jsfiddle showing the basics](http://jsfiddle.net/afSK8/51/). The important stuff summarized (with a conditional comment adding an .old-ie class):

```
    .wrap {
        float: left;
        height: 100px; /* any fixed amount */
    }
    .wrap2 {
        height: inherit;
    }
    .content {
        display: table-cell;
        height: inherit;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .old-ie .wrap{
        position: relative;
    }
    .old-ie .wrap2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
    }
    .old-ie .content {
        position: relative;
        top: -50%;
        display: block;
    }
```

Here's a [jsfiddle that deliberately highlight the minor faults](http://jsfiddle.net/afSK8/57/) with this method. Note how:

- In standards browsers, content that exceeds the height of the wrapper element stops centering and starts going down the page. This isn't a big problem (probably looks better than creeping up the page), and can be avoided by avoiding content that is too big (note that unless I've overlooked something, overflow methods like `overflow: auto;` don't seem to work)
- In old IE, the content element doesn't stretch to fill the available space - the height is the height of the content, not of the container.

Those are pretty minor limitations, but worth being aware of.

[Code and idea adapted from here](http://www.andy-howard.com/verticalAndHorizontalAlignment/index.html)

Comment: If you need a fluid/dynamic height as well as a position: absolute / float wrapper, see this trick http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256012/568458

Answer (score 6):

An element styled as follows will be aligned vertically to middle:

```
.content{
     position:relative;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     top:50%;
}
```

**However,** the parent element must have a fixed height. 
See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/15d0qfdg/12/

Answer (score 5):

see this bin:
http://jsbin.com/yacom/2/edit

should set parent element to

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I wanted to center in a parent container with position: absolute.

```
<div class="absolute-container">
    <div class="parent-container">
        <div class="centered-content">
            My content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had to add some positioning for top, bottom, left & right.

```
.absolute-container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

.parent-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table
}

.centered-content {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you still using float...

try to remove "float" and wrap it with display:table

example :

```
<div style="display:table">
 <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">
       Hai i'm center here Lol
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This. table-cell must not be floated.

Answer (score 2):

Float it with another wrapper without using `display: table;`, it works:

```
<div style="float: right;">
   <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 50%; height: 50%;">I am vertically aligned on your right! ^^</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometime floats brake the vertical align, is better to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height for the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the float from the element which has table-cell set on it.