# Buttons inside a ASP gridview with IE8 issue

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer, web

I'm having trouble rendering an ASP.NET gridview with internet explorer 8. It works fine in other browsers but IE is giving me issues.

When a user clicks the edit button it will display a save/cancel button, but they seem to not get put on the same row in IE. In other browsers it will decrease the size of the cells and tile the buttons appropriately.

It looks like this in IE8:
[image: IE]

This is the way it should look (from Opera):
[image: Proper]

The code for generating the gridview can be found in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7w7Anifj).

And the css for the gridview styling can be found in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NKXXXGx2)

I also perform a css reset [as such](http://pastebin.com/0WaEKcsV), so I'm not so sure why I'm having this issue as that should take care of the default values, I also use the XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype which should force IE into the slightly more standardized mode.

I'd appreciate an any pointers or help,
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 seems to have a lot of known width calculation bugs:

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/ie8-bug-max-width-overflow

http://edskes.net/ie/ie8overflowandexpandingboxbugs.htm

[internet explorer 8 ignores width for 'display: table-cell' element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608278/internet-explorer-8-ignores-width-for-display-table-cell-element)

You may need to force the width of the table cell manually, or wrap the contents of the cell in a div with a forced width.

Comment: Thanks. Solved it by forcing a width on the edit columns. For anyone else with similar issues I used a Itemstyle: <ItemStyle Width="55px" />