# Table 3 column does not work on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

On IE8 (strict mode, I can not use normal mode) is not displayed correctly the 3-column layout. This is a two-column layout: http://jsfiddle.net/JWBgY/ the second div rightly occupies the remaining space. This is the three-column layout: http://jsfiddle.net/JWBgY/2/ works on all browsers, but on IE8 and below the central width does not occupy the remaining space. I also tried to add `*width: auto`, but it does not work. How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you came across a well known bug/quirk for IE8 and table cell.

See: [internet explorer 8 ignores width for 'display: table-cell' element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608278/internet-explorer-8-ignores-width-for-display-table-cell-element)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you apply to my code please? http://jsfiddle.net/JWBgY/2/

Comment: I did not understand how to apply...

Comment: I checked your fiddle in IE10 using the developer tools.  Your fiddle works in IE8 mode but not IE7.  I just want to make sure that we are looking at the same problem. Please confirm.

Comment: That's right, but it does not work on IE8 strict mode.

Comment: I can't seem to see the problem in IE8 using the IE10 developer tool, so I can't do much more than this.  I tried changing the doctype in the fiddle but still could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: I see the same both in IE8 is in IE7. However, do you know a solution for IE7?