# Text doesn't wrap in table layout, overflows

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, overflow, word-wrap

I have a layout that uses `display: flexbox;` to centre content, amongst other things. As IE9 and below do not support this I've used a `display: table;` method instead with *almost* works a treat.

The problem I'm having is in IE8 (Yes I know, but I have to). For some reason the text escapes it's container, which has `display: table-call;` set on it. I've never experienced this before using this method and was hoping someone can help. Here is a screenshot of what occurs. with the `img` and `figcaption` coloured so you can see there width easier:

[image: Text breaking out of table layout]
As you can see, the text breaks out of the `figcaption`.

Here is the mark-up for the code:

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>
        <h3>E-commerce + Retail</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </figcaption>
    <img src="img/content/ipad.png" alt="ALT TEXT." class="ipad" />
</figure>
```

And also the CSS:

```
figure {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

figcaption,
.ipad {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ipad {
    width: 48.4375%;
    max-width: 620px;
}

figcaption {
    padding: 0 8% 0 2%;
    width: 51.5625%;
}
```

The original figcaption width was '41.5625%;', taking into account the padding. But I think table-cell's take this into account themselves, so I've set the width as the *actual* width. Seems to work in everything else, bar IE8!

Thanks, really hope someone can shed some light on this annoying little glitch!

Comment: Maybe you hit this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608278/internet-explorer-8-ignores-width-for-display-table-cell-element make sure to also read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7735363/451480

Comment: Thanks, I checked out that thread before posting but unfortunately none of the fixes suggested seemed to work. Maybe because I have 2 div's side-by-side, so display block or inline-block won't work. Cheers again!

Answer (score 1):

at `<figcaption>` use `word-wrap: break-word;`

That should do what you want.

FYI though, there are other ways that you can contain the text within it's parent element other than the one specified.

Comment: Also i should have added to my last answer that the reason the width : % isn't working in properly in IE is because none of the parents has an actual width set. thus IE doesn't know how to calculate `width: %` since it has no reference point to use for calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it's all a percentage layout. I guess with it being IE8 it's not worth going through and changing it all. The fix didn't work but I assume that is because of the percentage layout again. Maybe I should just set the `<p>` tag to have a width of 90% which should do it?

Comment: If you can post me a jsfiddle link with some working code, i can take a look and give you a workaround that will work

Comment: I've added everything into a codepen: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/OVJGWp. I've include my base styles, then the 600px+ styles (I've not bothered putting them in a media-query for this. And then my no-flexbox styles for IE9 and below, which is where the display: table; is set. At the bottom of the CSS you'll see some styling on a class of lt-ie9. That's my 'solution' so far, it doesn't fix the bug but at least the text doesn't overlap. Cheers!