# Why was the CSS property display:table added?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain to a css/html learner why I would style a generic html element (e.g. `<div>`) with display:table rather than simply using the HTML table tag? It seems to me that the latter would be the one to choose since it's implemented especially for the purpose of presenting table data, but I know the former wouldn't have come into being without a good reason. I just haven't been able to come across a decent explanation. My usually-quite-reliable friend, Google hasn't been able to offer me much help on this one.

Thank you in advance!
Niall

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: I could ask the same about display:list-item versus <li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several reasons, including the following:

1. To make it possible to style XML documents using tabular layout. CSS is not just for HTML.
2. To document the default rendering of HTML `table` elements in CSS terms.
3. To make it possible to use (simple) table layout for data marked up using e.g. `div` elements.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, Jukka. Really valuable answer. You've just given me one of the _aha!_ moments with the realisation that CSS is not just for HTML (of course it isn't now that you mention it), similar to when I first came across javascript in a non-DOM, non-web context.

Comment: It's difficult to single out an answer as correct in this context because all the answers given balance each other out and throw light on different aspects of the subject but this answer is the most comprehensive and directly related to the question so far in my humble opinion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` were added for use as default `display` properties for `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` respectively.

Outside of their defaults they are generally used for hacks like [centering text vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005309/div-table-cell-vertical-align-not-working) or [pseudo-element clearfixing](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) for example. Basically don't do it unless you need one of these hacks, especially don't do it if you want to implement a table as it will not be semantically correct leading to accessibility issues.

A word of warning, [using display:table has semantic effects in some screen readers](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201110/using_displaytable_has_semantic_effects_in_some_screen_readers/). This could lead to a section in your site that has multiple meaning for users using assistive technology.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to call these properties `hacks.` They were added to the CSS specification for a reason. Cementing hacks in spec updates would be counterproductive long term.

Comment: They're hacks for using them for anything other than tables. They need to exist for the table element to work.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Tyriar. But surely there must a good-practice use for display:table apart from hacks and fixes?

Comment: Thank you again, Tyriar. Your edited answer is really helpful for me. It's amazing how many high-profile tutorial sites advise using these properties for page layout without a mention of any semantic considerations. For learners like me it can get fairly confusing. Thanks again!

Comment: I actually just learned about the screen reader thing too :P I have never used `display:table` as pretty much everything can be accomplished without it.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few reasons to not use a HTML table but instead build a CSS table. But first, check to see the stats for your site and what browsers you need to support. You may need to support visitors that use older browsers that don't support display:table - eg IE7 http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Atable

One reason to use CSS tables is to separate the formatting from the content. If you ever wanted to manipulate the data into another structure at a later date, you would have to replace all of the table code rather than just tweaking the CSS.

Another reason is to make the tabular data responsive. You can have a lot more control over the data if it's divs than if it's a HTML table. You may choose to rewrap the content as lists, or hide, show, scroll, truncate... the content as you see fit. While some of this is still possible with HTML tables, not all of it is.

Comment: Thank you! My simple mind is actually able to grasp that explanation!